# How I can create an automatic Pull request on Github using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to create a pull request on Github from Azure Pipelines?

If there is not currently anyway:

Can you recomed the simplest way todo do it?
Can I use the Azure Pipeline Github connection to create the PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have published an Azure pipeline task to achieve this task.

URL: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=elranu.github-pr-tasks

Git repo: https://github.com/elranu/Github-PR-tasks